# iPhone webapp change "Done" button

Tags: iphone, web-applications

I'm developing a webapp on the iPhone. When entering text in a textfield, a keyboard pops up. Is there a way to change the wording for the "Done" key or hide it? I know how to change the "return" key, I want to change the blue "Done" key.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the web application itself , 'done' button is part of mobile safari user interface...No you can't to this from inside your web-app...
The only way to implement something like this (only for jailbroken devices) , is creating a mobilesubstrate hook for mobilesafari (exported as a dynamic library) , for changing any (possible) attributes of the desired subview...

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the response. I understand the button is part of mobile safari user interface but just wondered if there was a chance to change it like you can with the "Return" key on the same interface. Oh well, not a huge surprise. Thanks again.